# Issue with updating selected records in Postgres target - Talend 7X Open studio

Tags: postgresql, talend

I am new to talend and facing issues while trying to implement the logic below. I need to translate a legacy data from oracle to postgres and below is the sample structure of the postgres target table.

```
tableseq(db sequence) casenumber legacynumber statusofcase
1 123 789 A
2 123 678 B
3 123 456 C
```

i have created various filters in the tmap component to insert the data in above format.

But for update scenarios i have taken my key as casenumber but i want to update the status of the record where the legacynumber is 456.

i cant take the legacynumber as key because a part of this update i will also need to update the legacynumber column to the some new number like 100.

basically i'm trying to achieve below SQL functionality in talend.

```
update tableA set legacynumber=100 where legacynumber=456 and casenumber=123;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a join on your target table, on a tMap preceding the DBOutput.
in tMap : join your to-Update-Flow with your target table : retrieve sequence corresponding to your legacy number (for 456=> 3). Add the sequence to your output flow as the update key.

Comment: when i join the table it comes as lookup and the look up tables are getting loaded before the process starts in that case the MAX(seq) from the table is coming as null.

Comment: let me know  if there is another way to join the table where in i can get max sequence from table after inserting.

Comment: Not sure i fully understand  the design of the job. Perhaps you could try to have a first subjob to insert data, and a second one to update ?